# inline-block with max-width won't have ellipsis

Tags: html, css, display, ellipsis

I had a `block` element in it there is a `inline`, and another `inline` that holds a coloured bullet (used as a mark for the text).

```css
.label-container {
  width: 160px; /* const width*/
}

.label {
  display: block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 1em); /* const max-width (parent - ~.highlighted mark)*/
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.highlighted-mark:after {
  content: '●';
}
```

```html
<div class="label-container">
  <span class="label">Label</span>
  <span class="highlighted-mark"></span>
</div>
```

The text sometimes overflows from the block so I need limiting this and adding an ellipsis in case this happens (ellipsis between after the text, before the mark.

In order to let the ellipsis show I had to turn the text element to a block with constant width. For the block to act *inline*-ish (it had to behave as an uniform inline text) I added the `float: left`.

I want to get other *inline* display properties that I do not get as it is above and I also do not want to do such a bad parctice (forcing *inline* properties onto a *block* only because of the need of ellipsis). I did not like this use of reduction of widths in order to fill the parent `.label-container`; I'd hope for something like `flex-grow` if it'd have act like `max-width`. [I already tried *inline-block*, which is enough for me regarding its *inline*-like-properties, but it won't work! I prefer not using dotdotdot though I have a license].

Any proposal for a change? :{

Comment: What didn't work about inline-block? https://jsfiddle.net/vykdmcqL/14/ - you can change `width` to `max-width` for the label element if you want the dot to appear next to the text: https://jsfiddle.net/vykdmcqL/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably try flexbox like this:

```css
.label-container {
  width: 160px; /* const width*/
  border:1px solid;
  display:flex;
}

.label {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.highlighted-mark:after {
  content: '●';
}
```

```html
<div class="label-container">
  <span class="label">Label</span>
  <span class="highlighted-mark"></span>
</div>
<div class="label-container">
  <span class="label">very looooooooong Label</span>
  <span class="highlighted-mark"></span>
</div>
```